# log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.xml]

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

This is the error I'm getting, but I'm using log4j.properties.  I don't understand why it's looking for this file when I've implemented with properties.  I thought this was an either/or??

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very sily.  It's in my PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml").  Duh